# Connect A 3rd Party API to ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, api, arcgis-rest-api, rest

I am making a REST API that provides lat-long coordinates. I would like to create a pipeline to feed this API into an ArcGIS Online map. Is this doable? I am a programmer. Can ArcGIS online parse a JSON file?

Comment: Possibly, but not possible to answer without more details about the API and its output format.